# Could ForeignKey field link different type Models in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

I need to use Django to achieve something like a tree,  node in this tree has a single parent, and many children.The problem is that the type of the nodes are not the same, they belong to different Model, although they all have one foreign keys named parent, but different in other fields and methods, and each node's parent is likely to be any other types of nodes.for a node, I want to know who is its parent and who is its childs.

I tried this:

```
class BaseNode(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, related_name="child_set")

    def add_child(self, node):
        self.child_set.add(node)
        self.save()

    def get_children(self, node):
        return self.child_set.all()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ANode(BaseNode):
    pass


class BNode(BaseNode):
    pass
```

When I execute this:

```
a = ANode()
b = BNode()
a.add_child(b)
```

There is an error:

> TypeError: 'ANode' instance expected, got <BNode: BNode object>

Comment: Your question would be more understandable if you would add some example code from your models.py (of at least one parent and one corresponding child).

Comment: Check out https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt package. From your description it seems that MPTT has everything you need.

Comment: Thanks for point it out, I added it. @Ellen McCastle

Comment: I study the MPTT, it is a good package, but in the tutorial all the node in the same Model, anyway to make nodes in different Models?